# Command which works at a single command but not in an iteration

Tags: javascript

I try to take a list from an iteration from a specific document.querySelectorAll(). I use this iteration:

```
for (i = 0; i < document.querySelector('li[dat*="era"]').length; ++i) { document.querySelectorAll('li[dat*="era"] ul li.title div')[i].textContent }
```

it give me back this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined at <anonymous>:2:64
```

it works only when I use a single value

```
document.querySelectorAll('li[dat*="era"] ul li.title div')[0].textContent
```

How is it possible to work as a single command but not as an iteration?

Example HTML:

```
<li id="r01" dat="era">
   <ul class="ref">
        <li class="sth"> </li>
        <li class="title">
            <div>
                Text 1 for retrieve
            </div>
        </li>
    <ul>
</li>
<li id="r02" dat="era">
   <ul class="ref">
        <li class="sth"> </li>
        <li class="title">
            <div>
                Text 2 for retrieve
            </div>
        </li>
    <ul>
</li>
```

Comment: why is the selector different for length and for content?

Comment: @NinaScholz it gives the same results. Even if I change the selector of length to a number i.e. 30 the error is still the same

Comment: can you post HTML?

Comment: are you sure you are getting error ? I am not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following snippet

```js
// Your code, doesnt throw error what you have specified. 
// But when document.querySelector returns null(when theres no specified tag, it throws

for (i = 0; i < document.querySelector('li[dat*="era"]').length; ++i) { document.querySelectorAll('li[dat*="era"] ul li.title div')[i].textContent }


// Use document.querySelectorAll(...) once for performance
var l = document.querySelectorAll('li[dat*="era"] ul li.title div')
for (i = 0; i < l.length; ++i) {
  console.log(l[i].textContent)
}
```

```html
<li id="r01" dat="era">
  <ul class="ref">
    <li class="sth"> sth 1 </li>
    <li class="title">
      <div>
        Text 1 for retrieve
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="r02" dat="era">
  <ul class="ref">
    <li class="sth">sth 2</li>
    <li class="title">
      <div>
        Text 2 for retrieve
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second solution works for me.